# Unity: adding custom function to Scriptable Object

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I want to add to my project CardSO - a scriptable object. I want to give it a name, points and for some cards a special behavior. how can I add a function to the SO field?
for most of the cards, it can be empty (or just returning 0), I hoped I can write a function the takes List and return int.
Any thoughts?

My current code layout:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "CardSO", menuName = "New CardSO", order = 0)]
public class CardSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public string name;
    public int points;
    public Sprite Sprite;
    
    // public int SpecialBehavior(List<CardSO>);
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... just implement it. If you need most cards without it why not have a base class and make the method [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual)

```
// Whatever shall be the default behavior
public virtual int SpecialBehavior(List<CardSO> cards) => -1;
```

and then make a special card child class that can [`override`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) this method and return whatever you need

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class SpecialCardSO : CardSO
{
    public override int SpecialBehavior (List<CardSO> cards)
    {
        // or whatever
        return cards.Length;
    }
}
```